# getting div with using code behind

Tags: c#, updatepanel

I have a div that resides as below:
Master page>content page>content>Update panel>table>**div**>gridview

I am trying to get the width of the div using:

```
<div runat="server" id="gridViewWrapper" style="width:820px;">

HtmlGenericControl curHeightctrl = (HtmlGenericControl)this.FindControl("gridViewWrapper");
string curWidth = Convert.ToString(curHeightctrl.Style["width"]);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(curWidth.ToString());
```

but I cannot get the width.  I have spent 5 hrs working on this and Googled it until my fingers are numb.  It seems as though it should work since the div is generated on the content page not from the master page. (I may be using some incorrect language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `FindControl`, you can access your control directly in the code behind by it's ID.

**Aspx** (stays the same) :

```
<div runat="server" id="gridViewWrapper" style="width: 820px;">
```

**CodeBehind** :

```
string width = gridViewWrapper.Style["width"];
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(width);
```

Also please note that `Style["width"]` is already a string (it will print `820px` directly) so you don't need to `Convert.ToString`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use:

```
string curWidth = curHeightctrl.Style["width"];
```

Comment: Correct answer here as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, please close the div tag in HTML (notice at the end of it /> not just >)

```
<div runat="server" id="gridViewWrapper" style="width:820px;"/>
```

or you can do

```
<div runat="server" id="gridViewWrapper" style="width:820px;"></div>
```

Second, the CodeBehind need to be on the content page if the div is in the content page, not in the master page. You should be able to access it:

```
string width = gridViewWrapper.Attributes.CssStyle["width"];
```

gridViewWrapper is accessible without needing to call FindControl, because you put runat="server" in the markups

Comment: You are correct, the div needs to be closed.  It is in my markup but I only coped out the opening of the div.  I should have closed it out fo r my sample to be more complete.